# AWS Cognito verifications attached role's unable to delete/recreate

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm facing a similar issue with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406541/aws-cognito-sms-role-cannot-create-or-assign-a-new-role), but for email instead of SMS.  It does not let me recreate or delete the role in the Cognito>userPool general settings>verifications dashboard.

While clicking on `save change` in the verification settings on my Cognito. An error appears and stuck in there and it says "Your roles are still being created".

I try to use AWS SDK for JavaScript with `describeUserPool` to log out what is the changes. It have a `SmsConfigurationFailure: 'InvalidSmsRoleTrustRelationshipException'` in the JSON output.

Comment: Can you edit your question a little bit? is not clear what you're asking. IAM roles take some time to create that's why you see this message but I'm not sure what you're asking